# Good practices for full-custom IC measurement?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, asic, chip-design

I am a Junior Analog IC Designer and I want to characterize a full-custom IC. The thing is that I want to do it well and I don't know any reference with good practices and PCB design guidelines for this.

Part of this IC is an OpAmp so I also would like to check references with some background when testing and characterizing these circuits in the lab.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really unspecific, why don't you list the IC and the parameters you want to check.

Comment: @laptop2d well, I want to check some general references but the IC contains some filters to be characterized below 10 kHz. Also an OpAmp and an OTA to be fully characterized (open-loop gain, CMRR, input-reffered offset voltage, output impedance and so on).

Comment: IC fabrication is expensive - junior employees aren't just turned loose without guidance, whoever paid for this will know what they want tested.  Ask them.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by checking app notes for similar parts on Analog, TI or Linear (also analog now) websites. There are app notes for characterizing any part of an op amp, including testing bias current, open loop gain, noise and more.

With all of the information on manufacturers websites, there is enough information to learn how to design, build and test most of the circuits that they make. All you need is a lot of reading time.

Edit:
Here is a [collection of circuits (or actually just one circuit)](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/simple-op-amp-measurements.html) to test for Offset, bias current, DC gain, AC gain, DC CMRR, DC PSRR, AC CMRR and AC PSRR.

It would do well for you to start poking through manufacturers websites and start reading app notes, get familiar with Jim Williams and Bob Pease

Comment: +1. Or the OP needs a guidance from a senior DFT engineer from nearby cubicle... What? All being fired? Good grief... and good luck with "full-custom IC".

Comment: @AliChen didnt get anything